# How can I reduce installation time for a data R package I am building?

Tags: r, compression, lazy-loading, r-package, rdata

**Alternative wording of Q: What factors determine walltime for the `lazyload DB` step of R package installation?**

I am developing an R package to make it easy for users to access consortium data. The size of the `data` directory is 4.5G, where all objects are compressed with `bzip2`. There are 202 individual .RData files, ranging from 133B to 24MB compressed.

When I install the package, the output looks something like this:

```
Downloading GitHub repo mypackage@HEAD
✓  checking for file ‘.../mypackage-1c6478a/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘mypackage’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘mypackage_1.0.0.tar.gz’ (1.3s)
   
* installing *source* package ‘mypackage’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (mypackage)
```

The `*** moving datasets to lazyload DB` step takes the longest, about 5 minutes. What dictates walltime for this step? Number of objects? Size of objects? File compression? Is there anything I can do to make it install faster?

**EDIT:** I *do* want all of the R objects to be lazy-loaded, and I want them all to have accompanying documentation, so I believe the best practice is to keep the .rda files in `data/`. I am specifically wondering if there is a way to **speed up the lazy-loading step when the package is being installed.**

Comment: Are you planning to have this on CRAN?

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau not currently, so I haven't looked into CRAN requirements. Are there size restrictions?

Comment: I *think* it is generally discouraged to put too many and/or too big data (without bringing good arguments) in CRAN packages. But it is a long time since I've read up on those policies.a

Comment: We're okay with it only being available through GitHub for now. Additional larger (and less frequently used) datasets are downloaded from a public URL if a particular function is called.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're adding your data to the `/data` folder. An alternative would to be to put it under `inst/`; for example `inst/extdata/` and the make the available for loading through functions in your package by using the path given for `system.file("extdata/mydataset.Rds", package="foo")`. Then you'll need to call that helper function to get your data.

I.e. something like this for a specific dataset:

```
loadPackageData <- function() {
  readRDS(system.file("extdata/foo.Rds", package="bar"))
}
```

**Edit:** To load multiple datasets you could do:

```
bar_data_files <- list.files(system.file("extdata", package = "bar"),
                       pattern = "\\.Rds$", full.names = TRUE)
barData <- setNames(lapply(bar_data_files, function(f) readRDS(f)), 
                    tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(bar_data_files)))

# Then to get the foo dataset:
barData$foo()

# Or view the dataset names:
names(barData)
```

Auto completion would also work here.

A more conventional approach could be:

```
loadBarData <- function(dataset) {
  bar_data_files <- list.files(".", #system.file("extdata", package = "bar"),
                               pattern = "\\.Rds$", full.names = TRUE)
  files_sans_ext <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(bar_data_files))
  if (missing(dataset)) {
    print(files_sans_ext)
  } else {
    if (!(dataset %in% files_sans_ext)) {
      stop("Could not match dataset", dataset)
    } else { 
      readRDS(bar_data_files[match(dataset, files_sans_ext)]) 
    }
  }
}

loadBarData() # List all available datasets
loadBarData("foo") # Loads "foo" is foo is found
```

You can of course expand upon this and define what you want to happen if you ask for multiple datasets (in a vector) and so on (e.g. combining in a list or combining the datasets into one if they are similar).

One can also imagine alternatives if the datasets are systematically named.

In any case, the idea is that you make it load on a function call.

Comment: Thanks, @AndersEllernBilgrau. I do want all data to be directly call-able, so this isn't a good solution for me. I am just wondering if there's something I can do to decrease the installation time, e.g. if more or less file compression makes it quicker for R to lazily load data.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly callable"? You can expand upon the idea and make the loading function more clever. I'll update the answer a bit to show what I mean.

Comment: I appreciate the options, but once the library is installed, we want it to be as easy as possible for users to use an object. If the tradeoff for that is for the package to take a few minutes to install once, I'm okay with that. By "directly callable" I mean I want someone to be able to do something like `library(mypackage); head(somedata)`. I will update my question to be more specific too.

Comment: Another important point - I want the names of objects to be autofilled as users start typing, which only works if the data are lazy-loaded. It sounds like this solution would save time at installation but would make the data less accessible during use of the package.

Comment: OK; I'd argue that the difference is complexity between `head(somedata)` and `head(bar$somedata())` is minimal and would get you much of the autocompleting you seek. But it's fair that this is not what you want.

As to make it directly callable with autocompletion, I guess you could also load the datasets eagerly and populate all the datasets in an  `R/zzz.R` file or via `.onLoad()` or `.onAttach()` upon the loading of the package. And then you'll probably end up with a memory-intensive long-loading package; but maybe that can be solved by `delayedAssign()`.